# Implementing dynamically created array of a class object (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, pointers

My code is something like this:

```
class cell{
 public:
 int v;
 int x[5];
}

cell **block; //initialized the size of the array as [5][5] in main
```

Now what I really want to do is that I want to copy values from one integer array to the v member of every object of this class above. Like:

`int arr[5][5];`

arr has integer values. I want to copy like this.

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++)*(*(block+i)+j).v=arr[i][j];
```

Quite surely this is not possible as my IDE states. It says "; Statement missing." and indicates towards the

`*(*(block+i)+j).v=arr[i][j];`

Also this is how I am initializing block though.

```
  int V=5;
block = new cell*[V+1];
for(int x__=0; x__<=V; ++x__)
{
    for(int y__=0; y__<=V; ++y__)
    {
        block[x__][y__].v=0 ;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: `block[i][j].v = arr[i][j];`

Comment: @godel9 That didn't work either.

Comment: I did edit my post now for the initialization statements.

@godel9 Basically the compiler is stuck with the error I mentioned. "; Statement missing"

Comment: "I am working on the pre-standard versions where vector template is unavailable." -- I'm so sorry for you. Really.

Comment: So Am I man. So am I. For myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing `block` correctly:

```
int V=5;
block = new cell*[V];
for(int x = 0; x < V; ++x)
{
    block[x] = new cell;
    for(int y = 0; y < V; ++y)
    {
        block[x][y].v = 0;
    }
}
```

You can then copy the 2D array using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < V; ++j)
        block[i][j].v = arr[i][j];
```

Also, I'd recommend you look into `std::vector` for arrays in C++, and you should be initializing the `v` member variable in a constructor.

Comment: I am working on the pre-standard versions where vector template is unavailable. So I can't use it. And I did use a constructor to initialize it. Ok I understood. Let me try this up.

Comment: If you're initializing `v` in the constructor, then you don't need to set `v` to zero when you're creating the `cell **` 2D array.

Comment: Yes I just removed that statement with the loop.

Comment: Okay. That was the problem only. Thanks @godel9 .

Comment: is `class cell(){..}` a vaild declaration of a class name?

Comment: No. That was a little goof-up. Sorry about that.

Comment: @godel9 There is a problem. The copying doesn't seem to take place correctly. Like the arr is correct but when I copy the values to corresponding indices in block. It takes place correctly to an extent. It goofs up a few entries.

Comment: @SanskarKatiyar Did you fix the range of the `j` loop variable? Right now, it only goes from 0 to 2.

Comment: @godel9 I am looking at your code and I don't understand why would j go from only 0 to 2?

Comment: @godel9 No. I am referencing to your piece of code. What do I do now?